# Get current zoom in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I need to create a `setZoom()` function in Cesium. For that, I believe I need to evaluate the current zoom so I can decide if I have to use the `zoomIn` or `zoomOut` to show what the user asks.

Does anyone know if it's possible to get the zoom level from the map when using Cesium? Or any other solution... Any tips are very welcome.

Does the function `getMagnitude()` does the trick?

Thanks!

Solution:

I put together all the tips emackey gave to me and got the following code:

```
var iniPos = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
iniPos = this.viewer.camera.position;
var cartographic = new Cesium.Cartographic();
cartographic.height = zoom * 1000;
cartographic.longitude = iniPos.x;
cartographic.latitude = iniPos.y;
var newPos = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartographicToCartesian(cartographic, newPos);
this.viewer.camera.setView({
    position: newPos
});
```

With that I'm able to define the height of the camera to a zoom parameter defined by the user.

Comment: The solution above mixes values from cartesian coordinates (x, y, z) with cartographic coordinates (lat, lon, alt), which typically won't work.  I've updated my answer below to include a "set height" function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cesium's default view is a 3D globe with a perspective view.  A typical 2D zoom level number doesn't fully describe the different resolutions that Cesium's camera can see.  Take a minute to read my full answer to [Determining the Map Scale of the Viewed Globe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129903/cesium-3d-determining-the-map-scale-of-the-viewed-globe/144496#144496) for a better explanation.

*EDIT 1:* The `camera.getMagnitude` function gets the "magnitude of the camera's position" which really means the distance to the center of the Earth.  This is probably not what you want, instead you want the altitude of the cartographic position.

*EDIT 2:* I've added a code snippet here that has buttons on it to set the camera's height to various altitudes.  Click "Run code snippet" at the bottom to see this in action, or copy just the JavaScript portion of this into [Sandcastle](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html) to run it there.  Note that this works best when the camera is looking straight down, as it moves the camera to a specific height without altering the lat/lon.  If the camera is off-axis, the mouse can "zoom" the camera along the look vector, which alters all three cartographic coordinates (lat, lon, and alt) at the same time.  It's a trickier calculation to move the camera to a specific height along that line, I don't have code for that handy and it might not really be what you want anyway.  Give this a try, see if it works for you.

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    navigationHelpButton: false,
    animation: false,
    timeline: false
});

var cartographic = new Cesium.Cartographic();
var cartesian = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
var camera = viewer.scene.camera;
var ellipsoid = viewer.scene.mapProjection.ellipsoid;
var toolbar = document.getElementById('toolbar');
toolbar.innerHTML = '<div id="hud"></div>' +
    '<button type="button" class="cesium-button" id="h1km">1km height</button>' +
    '<button type="button" class="cesium-button" id="h10km">10km height</button>' +
    '<button type="button" class="cesium-button" id="h500km">500km height</button>';

toolbar.setAttribute('style', 'background: rgba(42,42,42,0.9); border-radius: 5px;');

var hud = document.getElementById('hud');

viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(function(clock) {
    ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic(camera.positionWC, cartographic);
    hud.innerHTML =
        'Lon: ' + Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.longitude).toFixed(3) + ' deg<br/>' +
        'Lat: ' + Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.latitude).toFixed(3) + ' deg<br/>' +
        'Alt: ' + (cartographic.height * 0.001).toFixed(1) + ' km';
});

function setHeightKm(heightInKilometers) {
    ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic(camera.position, cartographic);
    cartographic.height = heightInKilometers * 1000;  // convert to meters
    ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(cartographic, cartesian);
    camera.position = cartesian;
}

document.getElementById('h1km').addEventListener('click', function() {
    setHeightKm(1);
}, false);

document.getElementById('h10km').addEventListener('click', function() {
    setHeightKm(10);
}, false);

document.getElementById('h500km').addEventListener('click', function() {
    setHeightKm(500);
}, false);
```

```css
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
    width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
    font-family: sans-serif; color: #edffff;
}
#toolbar {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
<div id="toolbar"></div>
```

Comment: so the getMagnitude() method gives me what? I saw your explanation and understand that the value can change from point to point,  but is there a way to define a camera distance to a certain point? Maybe the camera height relative to map center? Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer with some sample code to get the camera's height, does that work for your case?

Comment: That's pretty much what I need, but in addition to getting its value I need to be able to set it... Is it possible?

Comment: Yes.  Essentially, you would convert `camera.position` (instead of `positionWC`) to cartesian coordinates, write to `cartographic.height`, then use `WGS84.cartographicToCartesian` to convert back, and assign the result of that back as `camera.position`.

Comment: I edited my question to include the solution I achieved with your help. I'm still not sure about the height, because sometimes I `zoomIn` and the height value decreases... I guess that's due to the differences on the land. If you have time, please check my solution and tell me what you think. Thanks a lot!